# Invalid Resource Id when batch inserting

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am doing a batch insert into the Google Calendar using the .NET API. I have the following code.

```
var request = new BatchRequest(calendarService);

request.Queue<Event>(
    calendarService.Events.Insert(
    new Event
    {                            
        Id = String.Format("yot-{0}", item.AppointmentId),
        Summary = item.Title,
        Description = item.Description,
        Start = new EventDateTime() { DateTime = item.Date },
        End = new EventDateTime() { DateTime = item.Date.AddHours(item.Length) }
    }, calendar.Id),
    (content, error, i, message) =>
    {
        //Log error
    });

request.ExecuteAsync();
```

When I execute and try and insert I get the error "Invalid resource id". What does this error mean?

Comment: Did you try to run the same request without using batch?

Comment: Doesn't work without batch either. It does work if I stop trying to set the Id but according this I should set the Id. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/

Comment: Are you following those rules: Identifier of the event. When creating new single or recurring events, you can specify their IDs. Provided IDs must follow these rules:
characters allowed in the ID are those used in base32hex encoding, i.e. lowercase letters a-v and digits 0-9, see section 3.1.2 in RFC2938
the length of the ID must be between 5 and 1024 characters
the ID must be unique per calendar. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Answer (score 2):

You have to follow the guidelines defined here : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Basically, the id has to be between 5 and 1024 characters long and consist solely from characters in this alphabet : 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv.

Try with a simple Guid.NewGuid() or [use a Base32 Encoder](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=base32) if you don't want random IDs

Comment: Please do not confuse [base32hex](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2938) with [base32](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648).